# HP Fanfic: HP finds a Peverell brother alive in underwater tomb

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

It's definitely been at least 5 years since I read this story. It was long in length, over 100k words. I think that I read it on Fanfiction.net.

I've read so many that it's hard to keep things straight in my mind, but what I know for sure is that:

Harry Potter found one of the Peverell Brothers in an underwater tomb. In some sort of stasis I believe. I think that he put himself in a stasis to help the future generation find a way to defeat death. I think he realized that one of the brothers was alive because he couldn't use the Resurrection stone to speak with him. This may have been about 1/2 or 2/3 of the way through the story.

I can't remember if there was any pairing.

Harry's main goal was to find a way to defeat death, the motto on his family's tombstone may have been a motivation factor to him: "The last enemy to be overcome is death".

Possible spoiler:

> I'm pretty sure he did end up finding a way to finally defeat death, it may have also ended with space colonization, but I could be totally off on that part.

(This is not Significant Digits, though if you read HPMOR I highly recommend you read that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Following the Phoenix](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10636246/36/Following-the-Phoenix) seems to be the one you're looking for.

The following lines from the story are consistent with the body of your question.

> Twelve hundred years old. Of course, Peverell had been asleep for most of the time. Not physically dead and kept under preservation charms as Harry had expected at first...the enchanted sleep Ignotus Peverell had placed himself under a thousand years ago, had actually kept his essential functions alive.

Comment: Can I suggest you try and provide more details that suggest similarity? As of now this is a good comment but a poor answer. It's a link only answer, which aren't answers. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer) to help you improve your answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad I've edited it to address your comment. Although I don't know how to use the spoiler-hiding mechanism...

Comment: Done and dusted.

Comment: @Edlothiad Thank You : )

Comment: Holy smokes, this is definitely it! How did you find it? I completely forgot that it was a HPMOR spinoff. That just makes everything better :D Super excited to read it again.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke -I was fascinated by HPMOR too. So, at that time, I hunted down a lot of hpmor spinoffs and read them. Significant Digits remains the best spin-off till date. Anyways,enjoy the story  : p